# Getting form value from PHP in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get a form input value from a php file to a javascript one, like this:
PHP file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> Search Customer by Field </title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/search-by-invoice-no.js"></script>
            <table id="results" border="1"></table>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

            if( isset($_GET["invoiceNo"]) && "" != $_GET["invoiceNo"])
            {

            }
            else
            {
                ?>

                <form id = "form1">
                Invoice Number <input id="invoice" name="invoiceNo" type="text" value="<?=isset($_GET['invoiceNo'])? $_GET['invoiceNo'] :""?>">
                <br/>
                <input id="submit_btn" type="submit">
                </form>

                <?php
            }
            ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

JS file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var invoiceNo = $('#invoice').val(); //Returns undefined
alert(invoiceNo); 
//etc...
```

Why this behaviour? I tried saveral other methods but all of them failed.

Comment: its undefined if the `<form ...` is not been printed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a couple errors: inverted if/else is the reason you are not getting a value and among other things you are missing a parenthesis on your php output inside the input and input elements should end with />

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> Search Customer by Field </title>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="../src/search-by-invoice-no.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

            if( isset($_GET["invoiceNo"]) && "" != $_GET["invoiceNo"])
            { ?>
                <form id = "form1" action='mypage.php' method='GET'>
                Invoice Number <input id="invoice" name="invoiceNo" type="text" value="<?php echo (isset($_GET['invoiceNo']))? $_GET['invoiceNo'] :""; ?>" />
                <br/>
                <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" />
                </form>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                   <p>No value received</p>
                   <input id="invoice" name="invoiceNo" type="hidden" value="0" />

                <?php
            }
            ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Also, you don't even need to check if it is set as you already do, so something like

```
Invoice Number <input id="invoice" name="invoiceNo" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['invoiceNo']; ?>" />
```

Will work fine too

EDIT

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title> Search Customer by Field </title>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){

                    var invoice = $('#invoice').val();
                                if(invoice == 0)
                                {
                                   alert('No value was passed');
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                   alert(invoice);
                                }
                });
            </script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <?php

            if( isset($_GET["invoiceNo"]) && "" != $_GET["invoiceNo"])
            { ?>
                <form id = "form1" action='mypage.php' method='GET'>
                Invoice Number <input id="invoice" name="invoiceNo" type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['invoiceNo']; ?>" />
                <br/>
                <input id="submit_btn" type="submit" />
                </form>
            <?php
            }
            else
            {
                ?>
                   <p>No value received</p>
                   <input id="invoice" name="invoiceNo" type="hidden" value="0" />

                <?php
            }
            ?>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: What is the difference? No short tags?

Comment: Yes I got rid of the short tag as we don't know his php config.

Comment: I made this way. invoice.length > 0 returns true, but .val() is undefined

Comment: Where are you getting $_GET["invoiceNo"] from and did you check if it is passed correctly ?

Comment: Well it should work. I'll edit my post with the script i'm using which works fine

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`/`else` structure makes no sense.  If $_GET['invoiceNo'] exists and isn't empty, then you do your `if` logic, so the form is never created.  But then, in your form, you check to see if $_GET['invoiceNo'] exists.  It never will, except if it's empty, so what's the point of using it there?

Comment: I see. So what would be the right way to do it? Sorry, new at this

Comment: Well, that depends on what you want to do.  It seems like you would only want your jQuery function to run if the form exists.  So, you could (1) display the form, regardless of what $_GET contains, (2) put the JavaScript script in the same part of the code that generates your form, or (3) only get the `.val()` of that field if `$('#invoice').length > 0`.

Comment: I made (3). The length returns > 0, but .val() still undefined

Comment: You should update your question with the new code; it's hard to help without seeing what you're trying.